# Logical OR and logical OR confounded by java?

Tags: java, android, logical-operators

I use this methode in order to check if a link is valid but when I use a logical OR it doesn't work but it works when i use a logical AND it's weird. What do you think?

```
   public String verification() {
    String lien = URL.getText().toString();
    if(titre.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        return "titreEmpty";
    }
   else if (lien.isEmpty()) {
        return "UrlEmpty";
    } else if (!lien.contains("http")) {
        return "notALink";
    } else if (!lien.contains("skydrive") || !lien.contains("youtube") ) { //the logical OR doesn't work 
        return "linkInvalid";
    }

    return "bon";
```

Comment: So what did not work?

Comment: I think you're reading it wrong.

Comment: Your first solution was correct, now it's incorrect. Now you require `lien` to both contain "skydrive" and "youtube".

Comment: when I use a logical OR here :``else if (!lien.contains("skydrive") || !lien.contains("youtube") )`` it doesn't work and i receive "linkInvalid" but if I use a logical AND it works

Comment: So what are you asking us for? You have to look into boolean logic.

Comment: I just want to check if lien contain skydrive OR youtube but it doesn't works with a logical OR but it works with the logical AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your condition:

```
!lien.contains("skydrive") || !lien.contains("youtube")
```

What happens in case when `lien` don't contain `skydrive`?
Entire condition is evaluated to

```
true || whatever
```

which will be evaluated to true, regardless if `lien` will contain `youtube` or not (which represents `whatever`).

Same goes for `youtube`. If `lien` will not contain `youtube`, condition must be evaluated to `true` because it will be `whatever || true`.

---

If you want to write condition that will say

```
if it is not true that line contains `skydrive` or line contains `youtube`  
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   (   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  )
if(       !         (          a                 |            b             ) )
```

you need to write it as

```
if (      !         ( line.contains("skydrive") || line.contains("youtube") ) )
```

or using [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `!( a | b )` <==> `!a && !b` like

```
if (                 !line.contains("skydrive") && !line.contains("youtube")   )
```

---

and here you have little proof of De Morgan's law where `1 = true`, `0 = false`

```
a | b | !a | !b | a|b | !(a|b) | !a & !b
--+---+----+----+-----+--------+---------
0 | 0 | 1  | 1  |  0  |   1    |    1
0 | 1 | 1  | 0  |  1  |   0    |    0
1 | 0 | 0  | 1  |  1  |   0    |    0
1 | 1 | 0  | 0  |  1  |   0    |    0
```

which shows that result of each case of `a` and `b` is the same for `!(a|b)` and `!a & !b`

Comment: Thanks I had forgotten the De Morgan's laws. if think this line `if ( !line.contains("skydrive") && line.contains("youtube") )` is wrong you forgot the parentheses

Comment: @DanSnow It is correct. Entire point of De Morgan's laws is to let us drop parenthesis, or wrap expression into them.

Comment: so you forgot the second "!" here `!line.contains("skydrive") && line.contains("youtube")`

Answer (score 2):

you are using an "!" so that means if something doesnt equal to something else

you are talking about this line right ?

```
else if (!lien.contains("skydrive") && !lien.contains("youtube") )
```

with simple words, AND activates when lien does NOT contain skydrive AND youtube,
OR activates when lien does NOT contain skydrive OR youtube, which would mean it would activate all the time

you are only getting confused because of the "!" :P

Comment: yes, it is the problem, i just want to check if lien contain skydrive OR youtube but it doesn't works with a logical OR but it works with the logical AND, that is the problem

Comment: why don you try removing the "!" ? the code is correct, you just have to understand why it works this way :P