# Do while loop that runs as long as user input isn't equal to certain words NOT working?

Tags: java, netbeans

I don't understand why this isn't working. The program always reprompts me no matter what I type in even if it is a valid action word.

```
String action = "";
        do {
        System.out.print("Enter what you want to do (ADD, REMOVE, "
                   + "LIST, SAVE, SORT): ");
        action = keyboard.next();
        } while ((!(action.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")) 
                || !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("REMOVE")) 
                || !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("LIST")) 
                || !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("SAVE")) 
                || !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("SORT"))));
```

Comment: De Morgan would be sad seeing your condition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: This has been asked a multitude of times.  I'll try to find the duplicate, but seriously people, providing more identical answers to this is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @DavidWallace What do you think about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968104/confusion-between-and-in-java

Comment: Yeah, @Pshemo, I hadn't seen that one before.  It's not quite what I was looking for, but I do like Oded's answer.

Comment: Here is one of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443398/logical-or-and-logical-or-confounded-by-java but I don't want to use dup-hammer on that since would rather find something better.

Comment: To simplify your problem: show me some number `x` that will not pass this condition `x!=1 || x!=2`. Try to test this condition on paper for number you want to give and you should notice something interesting. In other words `!(x==1 || x==2)` is not the same as `x!=1 || x!=2`.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. You used or, but you wanted and.

```
((!(action.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")) 
            && !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("REMOVE")) 
            && !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("LIST")) 
            && !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("SAVE")) 
            && !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("SORT"))));
```

Every word will satisfy the test not ADD or not REMOVE. You might apply [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) like,

```
(!(action.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")  
        || action.equalsIgnoreCase("REMOVE") 
        || action.equalsIgnoreCase("LIST") 
        || action.equalsIgnoreCase("SAVE") 
        || action.equalsIgnoreCase("SORT")))
```

Comment: @MinaHan these conditions are mutually-exclusive so only one of them can be fulfilled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your combined `while` condition is always `true`. If `!(action.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")` is `false`, then your `action` string must be `"ADD"`. So all the other conditions will be `true`. So the whole condition is `true`.

Replace your `||` with `&&`.

Alternatively, put your words in a `List` or other container and test

```
while (!words.contains(action))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong. You should terminate the loop if `action` isn't equals to any of the valid action words, but your condition continues the loop as long as `action` isn't equal to at least one of the valid actions, which is always true (since valid can only be equal to at most one valid action at a time).

The correct condition should be :

```
    } while ((!(action.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")) 
            && !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("REMOVE")) 
            && !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("LIST")) 
            && !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("SAVE")) 
            && !(action.equalsIgnoreCase("SORT"))));
```

Comment: @MinaHan The loop (after my suggested fix) would continue as long as action is not equal to all of them, which means it will exit when action is equal to one of them.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String action = "";
    do {
    System.out.print("Enter what you want to do (ADD, REMOVE, "
               + "LIST, SAVE, SORT): ");
    action = keyboard.next();
    } while (!((action.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")) 
            || (action.equalsIgnoreCase("REMOVE")) 
            || (action.equalsIgnoreCase("LIST")) 
            || (action.equalsIgnoreCase("SAVE")) 
            || (action.equalsIgnoreCase("SORT"))));
```